# How was Euler's number defined using logarithmic differentiation?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

Consider a well known definition of e: the limit of $(1+ 1/n)^n$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

I was under the impression that this was the first formula giving the exact value of e. This would make sense as Euler first observed the number (as far as I know) in compound interest computations, and this formula is in fact computing continuously compounded interest.

If I am in error, please help guide me toward truth.

If not, then here is my question:

Assuming I have not overlooked a simpler method of computing the limit, we must take the natural log of the limit before employing L'Hopital's rule and exponentiating to ultimately yield e...

But e is in the definition of the natural log, so wouldn't this be a circular argument to show that this limit is equal to e?

Comment: Yes, it is circular. At the end of the day this proof should proceed by introducing the exponential function $\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$ and then showing that its inverse, $\ln$, is smooth and satisfies $\ln(x^n)=n \ln(x)$ for $x>0$. Using L'Hopital's rule then tells you that $\ln \left ( \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n \right )^n = 1$, from which it follows that $e$ in the sense you gave is the same as $\exp(1)$.

Comment: You don't need $e$ to define the natural logarithm. $\log$ is the only antiderivative of $1/x$ satisfying $\log(1) = 0$.

Comment: We don't really "yield $e$", since we don't know what $e$ is. For example, you might prove that $(1+1/n)^n$ is bounded above by $3$ and increasing. Thus the limit exists. What the limit is requires more.

Comment: You can also define $\exp(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1 + x/n)^n$ (after doing some work to show that the limit exists for all $x$) and then show that $\exp$ so defined has all the expected properties.

Comment: Actually, [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#History) is credited with discovering $e$ first, according to Wikipedia.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it necessary to take the natural log of the limit to calculate it. It is possible to show that the limit converges to the same limit as $1+1+\frac 1{2!} +\frac 1{3!}+\dots $ which converges rapidly. This involves the binomial expansion of the expression.

Comment: The *real* question should be "what is your definition of $e$?" Presumably, you want $e$ to be defined by something other than $\lim(1+1/n)^n$, or else there wouldn't be anything to prove here...

Comment: The answer to the question as it's posted is "yes, you are overlooking a simpler method. There are other ways to define e that do not depend on the natural logarithm."

Comment: Once you have defined the limit in question to be $e$, you have already computed the limit. You don't need to take logs and all that. If you want to express $e$ in decimals to get a real feel, then that is another matter which is easily solved by showing that the limit in question is equal to sum of infinite series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}1/k!$ and add 13 terms of the series to get the value of $e$ to 10 places of decimals (this can be done by hand/pen/paper calculation in few minutes).

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, if you use this limit to define $e$, then, by definition, it *is* $e$, as long as you've shown the limit exists. You can't prove it is $e$ if you don't have $e$ defined.

We can show the limit exists.

A typical elementary way is to show that $a_n=(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing and has upper bound $3.$ Thus a limit exists.

Increasing means $a_{n+1}> a_n$ or $$\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}>\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}$$

or $$\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}>\frac{n}{n+1}$$

which follows from Bernoulli's inequality.

The upper bound can be seen by noting that:

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n^k}\binom{n}{k}<\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}<1+1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}=3$$

That the value $e$ has such lovely properties is another matter, but we can actually start with defining $$\exp(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n,$$ first showing the limit exists and then proving via elementary means that $\exp(x)\exp(y)=\exp(x+y)$ and other properties.

Comment: *"But e is in the definition of the natural log, so wouldn't this be a circular argument to show that this limit is equal to e?"* I believe this was the only sentence ending with a question mark, though it appears to have been missed here.

Comment: The question really is pertaining to how the limit definition of e is derived, which this answer answers.

Comment: It's sort of a vague, yes, but there is an implicit question here - how do we show this limit exists if we don't know about the natural logarithm?

Comment: @Kaynex I would assume so as well. I suppose we can wait to see what the OP thinks.

Comment: Calculating $e$ down from your upper bound of 3 requires for example:  $e=3-\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)(k+2)!}$. Definitely not as simple and attractive as $e = \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \sum_\limits{k=0}^n \frac {1}{k!}$.

Comment: The goal wasn't to provide the simplest definition of $e$, only to show that the limit exists, using only the definition that comes from considering compounding interest. @JamesArathoon

Answer (score 2):

There are two common definitions of $e$

$e = \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac {1}{n})^n$

and

$e = \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \sum_\limits{k=0}^n \frac {1}{k!}$

The first one comes from the compound interest calculation, and is actually the older to the two.

The second is usually first encountered with the Taylor series of $e^x$ but is frequently more useful.  Certainly it is easier to use to find an aproximation for $e.$

Are these two definitions equal?

Do a binomial expansion on $(1+\frac {1}{n})^n$

$1 + 1 + \frac {n-1}{2n} + \frac {(n-1)(n-2)}{6n^2} + \cdots +\frac{(n-1)!}{n!n^{n-1}}$

$1 + 1 + \frac {1}{2!}(1-\frac {1}{n}) + \frac {1}{3!}(1-\frac {1}{n})(1-\frac {2}{n}) + \cdots + \frac {1}{n!} (1 - \frac {1}{n})\cdots(1-\frac {n-1}{n}) \le \sum_\limits{k=0}^n \frac {1}{k!}$

Choose $m<n$

$1 + 1 + \frac {1}{2!}(1-\frac {1}{n}) + \cdots + \frac {1}{m!} (1 - \frac {1}{n})\cdots(1-\frac {m-1}{n})\le (1+\frac {1}{n})^n \le \sum_\limits{k=0}^n \frac {1}{k!}$

Keeping $m$ fixed let $n$ go to infinity.

$1 + 1 + \frac {1}{2!} + \frac {1}{3!} + \cdots + \frac {1}{m!}\le  \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac {1}{n})^n\le \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \sum_\limits{k=0}^n \frac {1}{k!}$

and now let $m$ approach infinity.

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac {1}{n})^n = \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \sum_\limits{k=0}^n \frac {1}{k!}$